# Lumen runs out of memory when calling dispatch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I get the following error when I try to call `dispatch` in my Lumen project:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 707

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

My first thought was to up the memory limit in `php.ini` to 1G but the process continues to eat up all of the application memory and then throws the above error.

Inside of my controller I have the following snippet of code:

```
private function attemptCapture(array $options = [])
{
    $response = array_merge(
        [
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => '',
        ],
        []
    );

    dispatch(new ExampleJob());

    return $response;
}
```

ExampleJob.php

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ExampleJob extends Job
{
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // dd('got here');  // this gets called
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('got here');
    }
}
```

I'm using the default Laravel `queue.php` in my `/config/queue.php` file and I'm using `redis` as the `QUEUE_DRIVER` and I'm using `default` as `QUEUE_REDIS_CONNECTION` as I'm assuming that will use the connection I've set up in my `redis['default']` in `database.php`

I'm baffled as to why this is failing, I get the same results even if I use the `sync` driver, dispatch just seems to screw up

*EDIT* After some further experimenting, it seems that when I call `dispatch` from a controller (passed from a HTTP route) then dispatch will attempt to call the route again instead of running the job or pushing the job to the queue.

This code gets invoked in the dispatch chain:

```
protected function callActionOnArrayBasedRoute($routeInfo)
{
    $action = $routeInfo[1];

    if (isset($action['uses'])) {
        return $this->prepareResponse($this->callControllerAction($routeInfo));
    }

        foreach ($action as $value) {
            if ($value instanceof Closure) {
                $closure = $value->bindTo(new RoutingClosure);
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            return $this->prepareResponse($this->call($closure, $routeInfo[2]));
        } catch (HttpResponseException $e) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        }
}
```

Which has: `array(1) { ["uses"]=> string(52) "App\Http\Controllers\Operator\CaptureController@test" }` as its payload that it receives.

I'm not trying to dispatch a new @test action, I want to dispatch ExampleJob

Comment: Show **ExampleJob** and `$this->operator->getCurrentWarehouse()` as well.

Comment: It’s the example job that comes with lumen and al I do in the handle method is echo ‘hello’;

Comment: I can safely get past that point if I comment out the dispatch of new examplejob.  It just returns a hard coded array of [id => 1] atm

Comment: Yea thats nice, show code of it, are you sure you are not recursively calling the same method over and over? Because thats your cause... *memory leak* or better yet *recursive function call leak*.

Comment: Also try instead of `echo 'hello';`, using logger `Log::info('got here');`. For  developing use `sync` driver and you *may* be able to see stack trace as well. Also what does `$this->acquireCaptureLock()` do?

Comment: I simplified the code to the above to isolate the error...the same still happens

Comment: Try adding `dd('got here as well')` to constructor of the job, while using sync driver.

Comment: Ok, so the constructor gets called, it seems to be falling over on `handle`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171001/discussion-between-kyslik-and-alex).